# Active Directory authentication in wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, adfs2.0

I am authenticating my ASP.Net application through Active Directory(Microsoft ADFS Proxy). Now I want to move this authentication to WCF service so that authentication will b done there and later on this service will b flexible. Let me know how to proceed for this and what are the binding types required for this

Comment: Is this the same question as here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627374/how-to-use-adfs-in-wcf-service

Comment: please don't post the same questions over and over again